# ActiveRecord Fuzzy Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm looking to perform a search to find an object similar to this:

`Object(id: 1, example: "abc")`

by using a search like this:

```
params[:search] = "abcdef"
Object.where("example LIKE ?", "#{params[:search]%")
```

but am only able to use the above example if my search has less characters than my object, not more.

Comment: I think the `LIKE` syntax would be as follows: `LIKE '%?%'` (the `%` being wildcard).

Comment: This makes no sense. You want an object with `example: "the"` to appear when somebody searches for "thesaurus"? This isn't how `LIKE` works, and you cannot make it work that way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working with legacy code and the associations I need aren't there. I'm going to try to use this search to makeshift a few associations between objects with inconsistent data. Do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be

```
params[:search] = "abcdef"
Object.where("example LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

Also might want to use `ilike` for case insensitive search (if you're using postgres)

Comment: @arel No, it doesn't: it warns against pure string conditions but this one is escaped with a question mark so it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: the fuzzily gem does not work with Rails 6. This solution has been deprecated.**

The [fuzzily](https://github.com/mezis/fuzzily) gem allows you to do fuzzy searching of ActiveRecord models that you've instrumented appropriately.

> Fuzzily finds misspelled, prefix, or partial needles in a haystack of strings. It's a fast, trigram-based, database-backed fuzzy string search/match engine for Rails.

Once you've installed the gem, you can instrument your model as follows:

```rb
class MyStuff < ActiveRecord::Base
  # assuming my_stuffs has a 'name' attribute
  fuzzily_searchable :name
end
```

You can then perform fuzzy searches as follows:

```rb
MyStuff.find_by_fuzzy_name('Some Name', :limit => 10)
# => records
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is true! :( Updating my answer to reflect this. Thanks for pointing it out :)